# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref

Tags: latex, pdflatex, overleaf

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{import}

% links Symbol
\usepackage{bbding,pifont}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Redefinition:
\let\orighref\href
\newcommand{\hrefa}[1]{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\HandRight}\,\orighref{...code}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hrefb}[1]{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\HandRight}\,\orighref{xxx/}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hrefc}[1]{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\HandRight}\,\orighref{ccc}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hrefd}[1]{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\HandRight}\,\orighref{vvv/}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hrefe}[1]{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\HandRight}\,\orighref{vvv}{#1}}
\newcommand{\hreff}[1]{\raisebox{-0.4ex}{\HandRight}\,\orighref{vvv}{#1}}
% end links symbol

% personal data
\name{...}
\title{}                               
\address{..}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+...4}
\email{xxx@a.com} 
\extrainfo{\hrefd{xc.com}}    
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{photo.jpg} 


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
```

Error:

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.40 \begin{document}
                     
The package hyperref has already been loaded with options:
  [hidelinks]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [unicode]
Adding the global options:
  hidelinks,unicode
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

when i try to convert to pdf, i get an empty html file.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution?

Comment: yes, i added `hidelinks` and `unicode` to `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,hidelinks,unicode]{moderncv} ` It suggests me to add `There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [unicode]
Adding the global options:
  ,unicode
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.`

Comment: Your definitions of `\hrefa` etc will break spectacularly as soon as your urls contain any fragile content. Try with `\hrefd{xc#.com}` and have fun ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `moderncv` class automatically loads the `hyperref` package. You can use `\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks}{hyperref}` to make sure it is loaded with the options you want.

(although your `hidelinks` option won't make a big difference because moderncv sets the line width of the link boxes to zero, so they are already invisible)

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks}{hyperref}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{import}

% links Symbol
\usepackage{bbding,pifont}

% personal data
\name{...}
\title{}                               
\address{..}{}{}
\phone[mobile]{+...4}
\email{xxx@a.com} 
%\extrainfo{\hrefd{xc.com}}    
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{photo.jpg} 


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
test

\url{stackoverflow.com}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there some possibily to combine with `\let\orighref\href
\newcommand` to add the symbol link?

Comment: @emoleumassi As said in the comment below your question, redefining your link in such a way is quite fragile. Use them at your own risk.